# Why is my if/else statement not working?

Tags: android, double, sharedpreferences, if-statement

I am a noob to android development and I am trying to use shared preferences to get values for a double during onCreate. However, my code for doing this seems to only work the first time I restart my app.  During, subsequent restarts the code doesn't work and skips over the if/else portion of my code.  This is very frustrating because if it works one time it should work every time.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void LoadPreferences(){
                            double portfoliocurrency1 = null;
            SharedPreferences portfoliopreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String isuser1created = portfoliopreferences.getString("U1C", "");
            if(isuser1created.equals("yes")){           
                String savedportfolioname = portfoliopreferences.getString("PN1", "");
                String saveddenomination = portfoliopreferences.getString("DN1", "");
                String savedporfoliocurrency = portfoliopreferences.getString("PC1", ""); //<--Always either "usd", "inr", or "eur".
                Log.d("test","SPConLoad=" + savedporfoliocurrency ); //<--Returns correct value on every restart.
                Log.d("test","USD=" + currencyUSD ); //<--Returns correct value on every restart.
                Log.d("test","EUR=" + currencyEUR ); //<--Returns correct value on every restart.
                pn1 = savedportfolioname;
                denomination1 = saveddenomination;
                if(savedporfoliocurrency=="usd"){ //<--If/else statement only works on first restart.  For some reason it is skipped on subsequent restarts.
                    portfoliocurrency1 = currencyUSD; 
                    Log.d("test","PC1USD=" + currencyUSD ); //<--Returns correct value on first restart.
                }else if(savedporfoliocurrency=="eur"){
                    portfoliocurrency1 = currencyEUR;
                    Log.d("test","PC1EUR=" + currencyEUR ); //<--Returns correct value on first restart.
                }else if(savedporfoliocurrency=="inr"){
                    portfoliocurrency1 = currencyINR; //<--Returns correct value on first restart.
                }
                Log.d("test","PC1onLoad=" + portfoliocurrency1 ); //<-- Only returns correct value during first restart.  Always returns null on subsequent restarts.
              }
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using String.equals() here, not ==.

```
if(savedporfoliocurrency=="usd"){
```

See, for example, the SO question [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).

==, as you found, will work sometimes, but it's not what you want to do here.  You want to check the contents, not the location where they're stored.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it and it works like a charm.  I had spent the last hour trying to figure out what was wrong.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
savedporfoliocurrency=="usd"
```

to

```
savedporfoliocurrency.equals("usd")
```

and in similar manar fix other string compares